# Qsot выдает переполнение стека [PascalABC.NET]

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Программа для быстрой сортировки на Паскале выдает переполнение стека на любом массиве, я понимаю, что проблема в рекурсии, но где именно - не понимаю.

```
const
    n = 10;
    type
    arr = array[1..n] of integer;
    var
    A : arr;
    k : shortint;
    
    function partition(A : arr; low, high : shortint) : shortint;
    var pivot,i,j: shortint;
    temp : integer;
    begin
        pivot := A[high];
        i := low;
        for j:= low to (high - 1) do begin
            if A[j] <= pivot then begin
                temp := A[i];
                A[i] := A[j];
                A[j] := temp;
                i := i + 1;
            end;
        temp := A[i];
        A[i] := A[high];
        A[high] := temp;
        
        partition := i;
        end;
    end;
    
    procedure quicksort(A : arr; low, high : shortint);
    var p : shortint;
    begin
        if low < high then begin
            p := partition(A,low,high);
            quicksort(A,low,p);
            quicksort(A,p+1,high);
        end;
    end;
    
    
    begin
        
        for k:= 1 to n do begin
            Write('A[',k,']=');
            ReadLn(A[k]);
        end;
        
        quicksort(A,1,n);
        WriteLn('_______________________________________________________________');
        
        for k:= 1 to n do begin
            WriteLn('A[',k,']=',A[k]);
        end;
        
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Массивы в процедуру надо было передавать по ссылке.

В описании процедур массив А нужно было передавать по ссылке, иначе масств будет передаваться по значению и все изменения массива будут происходить только внутри процедур.

Для передачи по сыслке надо было написать `var A : arr`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/836465)

Comment: @ksa является, просто плохим.

Comment: @Kromster, как скажешь...